# How to access named or anonymous Docker volumes on Docker for Windows?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-for-windows

If I run `docker-compose up` with the `docker-compose.yml` below it runs successfully but I'm unable to find the volume anywhere in my Windows 10 files. I checked in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks` but it is empty.

```
version: "3"
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:12.2
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

---

If I try specifying the host location for the volume with a Windows path like below I get an error about permissions

```
version: "3"
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:12.2
    volumes:
      - c:/docker-volumes/database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

---

```
database_1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
database_1  | This user must also own the server process.
database_1  |
database_1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".    
database_1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".     
database_1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".       
database_1  |
database_1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
database_1  |
database_1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... 
ok
database_1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
database_1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
database_1  | selecting default max_connections ... 20
database_1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
database_1  | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
database_1  | creating configuration files ... ok
database_1  | running bootstrap script ... 2020-04-27 21:00:29.194 UTC [81] FATAL:  
data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
database_1  | 2020-04-27 21:00:29.194 UTC [81] HINT:  The server must be started by 
the user that owns the data directory.
database_1  | child process exited with exit code 1
database_1  | initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

What is the easiest way to automatically transfer docker container files like this postgres database to the Windows 10 host?

Answer (score 1):

Since docker contents are present in separate container and docker keeps its own file system , so you need to go inside the container to view docker container files.

For this you need to run the following command from command prompt :

`docker exec -it <container-id> bash`.

I have tried with same docker-compose.yml mentioned in your question and after running docker-compose up , this is the way I was able to view content of container files :

[image]

Comment: That's useful for viewing the file system of the container, but doesn't use volumes and doesn't get the files on into Windows. I'd like to be able to access the data on the Windows host using volumes. Is that possible? I can't find any docs or GitHub issues saying it's not possible but also can't find any clear answer on how to do it